# Having trouble building docker container with certbot certs

Tags: reactjs, docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

I have a simple react app (for fun not work or school).  I use EC2 to run react, express, mongo using docker.  I have been trying to add SSL certs and having an awful time. I think certbot is the easiest but I have not had any luck.

Latest issue is I created the certbot certs manually on my local machine using dns challenge.  So I have my "/etc/letsencrypt/live". folder with my pem files.

in my docker file I want to copy those certs to my /etc/ssl directory to use in my docker image and I get no such file exists every time.  I think its because they are just sim links?

COPY /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyy.com/fullchain.pem /etc/letsencrypt

That file is in that folder but I do not know how to use it in my docker image because I cannot copy it.

My assumption is I can build this docker image locally with certs and push it to my ec2 instance and have it all work.

any help would be great or links to walk throughs? I could not find any good ones

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to call certbot from inside your container, because it will try to provision the same certificate multiple time.

I recommend instead one of those 3 approaches, depending on how you are using AWS:

- [Use AWS certificate manager with a Load Balancer or Cloudfront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/configure-acm-certificates-ec2/)
- Use certbot in your EC2 but outside of docker along [nginx (or apache2) as a reverse proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-free-ssltls-certificates-from-lets-encrypt-with-nginx/)
- Use certbot in your EC2 but outside of docker and mount the folder containing the certificates as a [docker volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) inside your container

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I thought about using an ELB but because this is just a fun project I did not want the monthly cost.  I have not tried using certbot just on my EC2 I was focused on containers and keeping it all within a single docker compose setup but I guess I have no real reason to need that. I will walk through a few of these and see how I do with them. thanks